# Go Mongo DB doesn't connect

Tags: mongodb, go, connection

I'm trying to connect to my mongo db atlas database, but I'm getting an error that I can't solve it within mongo+go forums.

The code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

func main(){

    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://my-user:<my-pass>@datalake0-lesz0.a.query.mongodb.net/my-db?ssl=true&authSource=admin"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
    err = client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    databases, err := client.ListDatabaseNames(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(databases)
}
```

The error:

connection() error occured during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) authentication failed, correlationID = 167bc5ba18415510a4144b7a
exit status 1

Comment: Have you whitelisted your public IP address in MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: I have inputed "Allow access from anywhere" on Atlas

Comment: Try entering `0.0.0.0` in the IP whitelist section and make sure that the URL, username, and passwords are correct.

Comment: `AuthenticationFailed` means it connected and submitted the credentials, but the server doesn't think that is the right user/password/database.

Comment: You are right, Joe. I used "<>", forgot to delete. sorry bout that, and tks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If the URI in the connect string is verbatim, then this is your problem:
`mongodb://my-user:<my-pass>` is incorrect, `<my-pass>` should be substituted with your password

You've probably cut and pasted the provided URI on completion of DB setup but this connect string does not include items like your password, also you gave `my-user` which, unless you set up the username `my-user` that also needs changing.